# Startx don't work

Tags: 20.04, interface

I'm trying to start the X Window System on my Ubuntu machine by running the command 'startx' in the terminal, but it's getting stuck at a certain point and I'm unable to proceed. Could someone please help me troubleshoot and resolve this issue? I've attached a screenshot of the error message I'm seeing. I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 and I haven't made any recent changes to my system. Thank you in advance for your help!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlZ98.png)

Comment: Please help us help you and tell us more about what you have: Are you running an installed system (or a live system booted from USB)? Are you running Ubuntu Desktop or Ubuntu Server? What comuter is it (brand name and model)? What graphics chip/card is there (brand name and model)?